# Update in hibernate with single database query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Suppose I have an employee class which has 3 fields - empId, empName and empAddress.

I want to update only address of employee with empId say 1. If I use session.update(emp), it will set empName as null, of course I don't want that.

Is there any way to achieve this in a single database query without using hql.

I wanted to replicate sql query : "update employee set empAddress = 'addr1' where empId = 1"

Comment: Why not use the value of `empName` which you actually want to be persisted?  Under the hood Hibernate is just running JDBC SQL queries.

Comment: I only have empId(identifier) and empAddress(fields I want to update).

Answer (score 0):

Refer [hibernate DML-style operations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct).

The hibernate Query interface now contains a method called executeUpdate() for executing HQL UPDATE:

```
String hql = "UPDATE Employee set empAddress = :empAddress "  + 
             "WHERE empId = :empId";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("empAddress", 1000);
query.setParameter("empId", 10);
int result = query.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("Rows affected: " + result);
```